# Move footer structure to html.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I've attempted to move the footer structure of a theme from page.tpl to html.tpl so the footer elements can occur outside of internal width specific layout.

In doing so I receive an error:

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in....

One of the many lines in question is:

```
<?php print render($page['footer_first']); ?>
```

Can someone explain what exactly the issue is here and how I can best solve it ? Muchly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks to you both @Teegan and Stephen for such speedy responses! I will take your comments on board and re-structure the page.tpl to have the correct layout markup, rather than trying to output it in html.tpl. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure what this error would be caused by but I would recommend instead of putting the footer into the html.tpl.php put a wrapper div around the other elements within the page.tpl.php excluding the footer and styling that wrapper with a specific width.

eg.

```
    <div class="wrapper" width="960">
      //all content in here
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      //footer here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the regions (for example $page['footer_first']) are not available in html.tpl.php. Why wouldnt you want to render it in the page.tpl.php? You can however create a hook like this:

(From drupal api page)

```
<?php
function hook_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['page']['page_bottom'][] = array('foo' => array('#markup' => 'foo'));
  // Or other render array stuff
}
?>
```